Sum of the reciprocal of $(3n+1)!$
I was playing around and came across the following sum
$$S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(3n+1)!}$$
$$S\approx 1.04187$$
My only intuition was the product form of the reciprocal gamma function, but that seemed to yield a harder problem. What would a proper solution development be?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Doesn't look great.

The method I know for this sum is to consider the differential equation $y'''=y$ for which $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3n+1}}{(3n+1)!}$ is the solution with $y(0)=0$, $y'(0)=1$ and $y''(0)=0$. Then plug in $y(1)$.

Yous hould be able to express $S$ as a simple linear combination of $e$, $e^\omega$ and $e^{\overline\omega}$ where $\omega$ is a third root of unity.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection

The decimal expansion of this infinite sum is OEIS sequence A143820.

Recall that
$$e^z = \sum_{ n =0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$$
holds for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$. Therefore
$$\frac{e^z}{z} = \sum_{ n =0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n-1}}{n!}$$
holds for $z\neq 0$. We can do a roots of unity filter with $\omega^3 = 1$, $\omega \neq 1$ to get
$$\frac{e^1}{1}+\frac{e^\omega}{\omega}+\frac{e^{\omega^2}}{\omega^2} = \sum_{ n =0}^{\infty}\frac{1^{n-1}+w^{n-1}+(w^2)^{n-1}}{n!} = \sum_{ n =0, n-1\equiv 0\pmod{3}}^{\infty}\frac{3}{n!}.$$
This works since, in Iverson brackets, $1^m+\omega^m+(\omega^2)^m = 3\cdot [m\equiv 0\pmod{3}]$. Therefore our answer is
$$\frac{\frac{e^1}{1}+\frac{e^\omega}{\omega}+\frac{e^{\omega^2}}{\omega^2}}{3} = \frac{\frac{e^1}{1}+\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}}{-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}+\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}}{-\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}}{3}$$
$$ = \frac{e}{3}+\frac{\sin(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})}{\sqrt{3e}}-\frac{\cos(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})}{3\sqrt{e}}$$
